# Solving for a system of vectors in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

A homework question asks:

Let $\alpha = (-3,5,2), (4,1,1), v_3$ and $\beta = w_1, (4, 0, -7), w_3$ be bases for $R^3$ and let 
$$
Q = [I]_{\alpha}^{\beta} = 
\begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 & 5\\ 
1 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find $v_3, w_1, w_3$.

**My Solution**

$v_3 = 5w_1 + 2w_2 - w_3$

From $Q^{-1}$ we obtain

$w_1 = 3v_1 + 5v_2 + v_3$

$w_3 = 7v_1 + 11v_2 + 2v_3$

Which we may organize into

$\begin{align*}
v_3 &- 5w_1 &+ w_3 &= (8,0,-14) \tag{1}\\
v_3 &- w_1 & &= (-11, -20, -11) \tag{2}\\
2v_3 & &-w_3 &= (-23, -46, -25) \tag{3} 
\end{align*}$

By computing the system for each 'column' it is possible to arrive at a solution for $v_3, w_1, w_3$. **But that requires a triple computation.  Is there a simpler way of doing what I'm trying to do?**

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the calculation you have done to obtain the three equations tagged (1), (2), and (3) are correct. I did not check that part of your text.

Let $$A=\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & -5 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0  & -1 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$
and
$$B=\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    8 & 0 & -14 \\
    -11 & -20 & -11 \\
    -23 & -46  & -25 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right].$$

Determinant of $A$ is equal to $-2$. This is a nonsingular square matrix and, therefore, you can find its inverse $A^{-1}$. Then, you can carry out the following matrix multiplication to obtain the three solution sets in one go.

$$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    v_{31} & v_{32} & v_{33}\\
    w_{11} & w_{12} & w_{13} \\
    w_{31} & w_{32} & w_{33} \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]=A^{-1}B=A^{-1}
\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    8 & 0 & -14 \\
    -11 & -20 & -11 \\
    -23 & -46  & -25 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$